# Two forms one submit - Submit, delay, submit

Tags: jquery, timeout

I am trying to submit two forms at once (one goes to db and the other goes to fpdf to make labels). I use jquery to copy the variables from the first form to hidden inputs on the second form. I have seen this question asked a couple times on here but none of the answers have helped. I use the 'fake' ajax method - ie: I set the form target to a hidden iframe on the same page. So I want to submit one form, then use a delay then submit the second form (because it's not working without the delay!)

So how do I add a delay to this code:

```
    $('#insert').submit(function() {
    //Delay here please, or is it timeout I need?
    $('#print').submit();
    });

<form id="insert" action="insert.php" target="hiddeniframe">
// a bunch of inputs
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form id="print" action="pdf.php" target="hiddeniframe">
// a bunch of inputs
</form>
```

Comment: @ChristianVarga I have never used ajax before, so I was trying to keep it simple. Also even if I was to use ajax I believe I would still have the same problem.

Comment: What exactly does the pdf.php script do? Does it return something, or make a file on the server? There's no reason why you can't submit 2 ajax requests at once (although to be honest you should only send the data once to one action on the server, then split up the insert and pdf action there).

Comment: @ChristianVarga actually it is required to have the target of the pdf form be to go to the iframe. Because the PDF is set to auto print and the browser opens it right away through the iframe and prints it.

Comment: To execute a function after a delay you use setTimeout like this: `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, time)`, where 'time' is in milliseconds. I don't think you that's what you want to do though, since you can't be sure how long the response will take. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064865/does-submit-function-has-a-callback (execute in onload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear on what your scripts are doing / returning, but you can always use ajax for the first request, then use the iframe for the second request. Eg:

```
$('#insert').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {
      // duplicate fields from first form into second form
      // as per whatever code you've already written

      // submit second form
      $('#print').submit();
    })
  });
});
```

This way the second form is submitted after the successful response of the first form.

Comment: I like this solution but I can't get it working to submit the second form. I don't need to duplicate the fields because that it is done on keyup already.

Comment: Chuck an `alert` / `console.log` in the success function to make sure it's firing. Also check firebug / developer tools to make sure there's no errors, and that the event is actually getting sent.

Comment: Ah just my lack of knowledge. I had a submit button for the second form and it appears the submit() won't work if the form has a submit button. All is well, this solution in awesome! Thanks