# Can't get Ajax to submit two forms (second dependent on success of the first) - on one page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm trying to use Ajax to submit two forms, one after the other, in such a way that after the first form successfully submit and makes a request to the API, then the second form makes a different request.

The second form should only trigger on success of the first.

I am using Rails 4.2, but am providing the rendered html of the two forms on one page is below:

```
<!-- FORM 1 -->

<form action="/reservations/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />


  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="partner_code" id="partner_code" value="DEV-DAN-BETH:73411" />
  </div>  
  <div class="field">    
   <input type="text" name="restaurant_location_id" id="restaurant_location_id" value="10799" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">    
    <input type="text" name="session_id" id="session_id" value="DINNER" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">    
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="dining_date_and_time" id="dining_date_and_time" value="2015-07-29T18:00:00+00:00" />
  </div>

   <div class="field">    
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="dateSubmit" id="dateSubmit" />
  </div>

   <div class="field">    
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="timeSubmit" id="timeSubmit" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">    
    <label for="size">Guests</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="size" id="size" value="2" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="Daniel" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="Easterman" />
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="bookEmail" id="bookEmail" />
  </div> 

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="bookSubmit" />
  </div>
</form>

<!-- FORM 2 -->

  <form action="/reservations/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="reservationId" id="reservationId" value="35347855" />        
  </div> 
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Below is the Ajax code I have tried so far. Because of how I've setup Rails, I cannot set the IDs of the forms, so I figured that instead of using serialize, I could distinguish the two forms by specifying the input values. (I know this is not DRY at all but I have limited experience with Ajax so I thought this could be the only way to do it).

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"partner_code": $("#partner_code").val(),
            "restaurant_location_id": $("#restaurant_location_id").val(),
            "session_id": $("#session_id").val(),
            "dining_date_and_time": $("#dining_date_and_time").val(),
            "size": $("#size").val(),
            "first_name": $("#first_name").val(),
            "last_name": $("#last_name").val(),
            "bookEmail": $("#bookEmail").val() }
    success: function() {
      // submit second form
      $('form').submit();
        data: { "reservationId": $("#reservationId").val() }
    }
  });
});
```

In the Rails docs it says the only thing you need to do is set remote to true in the form to get Ajax to work (this renders data-remote="true" in the HTML). Also, I have read that prevent default is key to stop the form's normal behaviour, but in this case it stops the form from submitting at all.

I found this to be the most relevant answer in my research: [Two forms one submit - Submit, delay, submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077974/two-forms-one-submit-submit-delay-submit) and have based my code on it, but the Chrome console and (Sublime plugin) keeps telling me there is a syntax error in the Javascript which I have tried (but failed) to debug.

Comment: Something feels wrong with having `$('form').submit();` within the submit event. Doesn't this loop forever?

Comment: @Niklas - the first thing is that the syntax is wrong in the Ajax request and I can't figure out how to debug it. I haven't even got to that stage of an infinite loop yet

Comment: try using `class/id` and on successful submit of form1 submit second form using its class/id

Comment: This part of the problem, @BharatSoni - I can't set the Ids for those forms the way I've done it in Rails. I need to find a way around this.

Comment: will there be only 2 form or there will be more?

Comment: Only 2 forms needed.

Comment: I am not saying this is the best way:

select `#reservationId` and select its parent form, something like this:

`$('#reservationId').closest('form').submit();`

Comment: Thanks @BharatSoni but how do I select the first form?

Comment: Also is the Ajax I provided clean enough syntax so it will work?

Comment: if first `form` is always first `form` then use:

$('form')[0] 

if you are not sure about the index of the `form` then you can use the same method, uses some `child` and then select parent from that.

Comment: everything looks fine in AJAX syntax.. are you facing any issues it that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85179/discussion-between-daneasterman-and-bharat-soni).

Comment: Yes, its telling me: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on line 14, on line starting:  `success: function() {`

Comment: you forgot a comma(,) after `data` property.

Comment: Also its the first form on this specific page, but there are other forms in the app - will the index approach [0] still work?

Comment: no, [0] approach will work only if it is the first form, use the same approach that we used in submission of second form, select a child(of which you are sure will be always present in form) and from that use `.closest('form')`

Comment: @daneasterman is everything working now..?

Comment: First form is submitting fine, but the API is telling me I am not supplying it with correct data in second form. I tried it out on another form on another page with exactly same data and it submits fine. If there are two forms on one page, I read u need to do something with iframe, and set a fake 2nd target page. (At the moment it is going to same page (reservations/new) as first form). Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your first form tag it having `data-remote=true`. thats why it's not calling ajax function and submitted with ujs. So change that first. Also you should have id for each form so try changes form as below:

```
<!-- FORM 1 -->

<form id="form1" action="/reservations/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />


  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="partner_code" id="partner_code" value="DEV-DAN-BETH:73411" />
  </div>  
  <div class="field">    
   <input type="text" name="restaurant_location_id" id="restaurant_location_id" value="10799" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">    
    <input type="text" name="session_id" id="session_id" value="DINNER" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">    
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="dining_date_and_time" id="dining_date_and_time" value="2015-07-29T18:00:00+00:00" />
  </div>

   <div class="field">    
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="dateSubmit" id="dateSubmit" />
  </div>

   <div class="field">    
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="timeSubmit" id="timeSubmit" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">    
    <label for="size">Guests</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="size" id="size" value="2" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="Daniel" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="Easterman" />
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="bookEmail" id="bookEmail" />
  </div> 

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="bookSubmit" />
  </div>
</form>

<!-- FORM 2 -->

  <form id="form2" action="/reservations/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" name="reservationId" id="reservationId" value="35347855" />        
  </div> 
</form>
```

and try change js as below:

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"partner_code": $("#partner_code").val(),
            "restaurant_location_id": $("#restaurant_location_id").val(),
            "session_id": $("#session_id").val(),
            "dining_date_and_time": $("#dining_date_and_time").val(),
            "size": $("#size").val(),
            "first_name": $("#first_name").val(),
            "last_name": $("#last_name").val(),
            "bookEmail": $("#bookEmail").val() }
    success: function() {
      // submit second form
      $('form2').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing that out @Dipak, that was a silly mistake by me, but I can't set the form Id as I'm using Rails and the form_tag helper is very limited in the way I've set it up.

Comment: Should I keep remote set to true for the second form though?

Comment: no you should not. It is being submitted by callback.

Comment: If you want to submit second form with asynchronously then you can add remote=ture in second form. You can do everything with form_tag html option they are not limited either.